# Should there be a "Kitzur Shulchan Aruch" tag?

Tags: feature-request, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

Many people on Mi Yodeya (including myself) use the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch as a source in our questions and answers.

Sometimes I have questions on certain phrases or passages in the Kitzur. Should there be a tag for it? There is currently a tag for "Shulchan Aruch", but the tag description is:

> A classic work of Jewish Law, compiled and written by R' Yosef Karo.

The Kitzur was not written by Karo, but by a Hungarian rabbi named Shlomo Ganzfried. I [recently asked a question concerning the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85839/why-does-specifically-searching-for-a-white-chicken-for-kapparos-resemble-the-a) on Mi Yodeya and went ahead and tagged it under "Shulchan Aruch" but I don't think it's exactly fitting.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1685/759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be quite a few questions addressing material from the *Kitzur*, at least some of them about the *Kitzur* itself as a work. It seems to me that it would make sense to have such a tag.

I wouldn't go back and apply it to every question that ever quoted the *Kitzur*, but ones that are tagged [shulchan-aruch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shulchan-aruch) but quote the *Kitzur* and not the *Shulchan Aruch* and ones that are about the *Kitzur* as a work would be good candidates for retagging.

Comment: So do you think I made the right choice in my decision to tag my question about the Kitzur with "shulchan-aruch" then?

Comment: @ezra Eh, it's not horrible. I agree with you that [tag:kitzur-shulchan-aruch] would be better.